# How to create folders based on variable length filenames through batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a set of files I wish to copy to a new set of subfolders.

For instance:
0_107_206.tif
1_0_69.tif
1_16_75.tif
1_40_117.tif
2_0_36.tif
2_26_62.tif
35_0_19.tif

These files are stored in folders based on the first substring of the filename such as 0, 1 or 35. I want to create subfolders based on the second substring between the 2 '_' characters. I have tried several things along the lines of

> SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
>       FOR %%B in (*.tif) DO (
>       SET FileName=%%B
>       SET FileName1=!FileName:~2!
>       SET FileName2=!FileName1:~0,-7!
>       MD %TargetPath%!FileName2!
>       )
>       ENDLOCAL

But this is not flexible enough. Is there a way to get the position of the '_' characters and feed that into a SUBSTRING function? Naturally this needs to work in a loop since there are thousands of files I need to proces.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOR %%B in (*.tif) DO (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%x in ("%%~B") do (
        md "%TargetPath%%%~y"
        copy %%~B "%TargetPath%%%~y\%%~B"
    )

)
```

?

Comment: Thanks, this works! I forgot about those for /f options. Only thing that I don't quite understand is what the %%x refers to?

Comment: it is the first token for the inner loop.in the code is used only the second one `%%y` and they are both defined with `"tokens=1,2"`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. +1 for the quick response

Comment: +1, though I would simpy use `"tokens=2"` and `%%x`, since the first token is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Given a file structure

```
u:\0\0_107_206.tif
u:\1\1_0_69.tif
u:\1\1_16_75.tif
u:\1\1_40_117.tif
u:\2\2_0_36.tif
u:\2\2_26_62.tif
u:\35\35_0_19.tif
```

Then this batch:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=u:"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*_*.tif" '
  ) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=_" %%B IN ("%%~na") DO (
   ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%C"
   ECHO COPY /b "%%a" "%destdir%\%%C\"
 )
GOTO :EOF
```

would generate

```
MD "c:\destdir\107"
COPY /b "u:\0\0_107_206.tif" "c:\destdir\107\"
MD "c:\destdir\0"
COPY /b "u:\1\1_0_69.tif" "c:\destdir\0\"
MD "c:\destdir\16"
COPY /b "u:\1\1_16_75.tif" "c:\destdir\16\"
MD "c:\destdir\40"
COPY /b "u:\1\1_40_117.tif" "c:\destdir\40\"
MD "c:\destdir\0"
COPY /b "u:\2\2_0_36.tif" "c:\destdir\0\"
MD "c:\destdir\26"
COPY /b "u:\2\2_26_62.tif" "c:\destdir\26\"
MD "c:\destdir\0"
COPY /b "u:\35\35_0_19.tif" "c:\destdir\0\"
```

So you'd just need to change source and destination directory names to suit; change the `copy` command to `move` if appropriate; remove the `ECHO` keywords to activate.

You could also append `2>nul` to the `MD` line to suppress the 'diretory already exists' message.

OR, you could replace the `COPY` with `XCOPY` and then the `MD` would become irrelevant.